# How to send JSON Object from POSTMAN to Restful webservices

Tags: java, mongodb, web-services, rest

I'm trying to send json from POSTMAN to RESTful webservice. I had followed this tutorial [url](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/perform/player-management/guides/postman.html) for sending json through POSTMAN.

**My URL :**

http://localhost:8080/myWebService/rest/dataInsert/insert

**My Service method:**

```
@POST
    @Path("/insert")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String insertData(JSONObject jsonlist) throws UnknownHostException;
```

**My Impl:**

```
@Override
    public String insertData(JSONObject jsonlist) throws UnknownHostException {
        System.out.println(jsonlist);
        insertDataDao.insertData(jsonlist);
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
```

**My DAO:**

```
public  String insertData(JSONObject jsonlist) throws UnknownHostException{
        System.out.println(jsonlist);
        MongoConnection mongoconnection = new MongoConnection();
        MongoClient mongoclient = mongoconnection.getMongoClient();

        MongoDatabase db = mongoclient.getDatabase("mydb");
        MongoCollection<Document> col = db.getCollection("col");

        String jsonString = jsonlist.toString();
        System.out.println(jsonString);

        Document doc = Document.parse(jsonString);
         col.insertOne(doc);
        System.out.println("Inserted Successfully !!!");
        return "SUCCESS";

    }
```

But I'm facing the below Exception:

> JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet CXFServlet threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;

I'm unable to fix this issue. Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

Comment: Which version of cxf you are using for your service

Comment: I'm using 2.7.13 version of cxf

Comment: Nothing wrong with the Postman call. can you add some code of the method , where you are making the request. And that methods return type should be Response. @dev777

Comment: You compilation time Jax-rs implementation is different compared to application runtime. Check which version of CXF is used by your JBOSS server.

Answer (score 45):

**Step 1**: open postman type your api url and select post type.

**Step 2**: goto Headers button type("Content-Type") first input box and type "application/json" in second input box it gives auto-complete suggestion

**Step 3**: goto Body button and choose raw radio button and choose JSON (application/json) in drop down in same raw right side.

**Step 4**: type your json like student object

```
{
  "name": "dummy",
  "marks": "26"
}
```

[image: check the attached sample example image]

Comment: Yes. I did the same thing. But I'm unable to send this json data to webservice. OnClick of send button in POSTMAN, I'm facing the issue which is mentioned above

Answer (score 11):

### POSTMAN V5.2.0 Testing

URL: http://localhost:8080/mail/user/register/

JSON Data:

```
{"name":"John","firstName":"Smith","lastName":"MT","email":"johnsmt@yahoo.com"}
```

Steps:

1. Add in Headers

```
key: content-type
value: application/json
```

2. Paste above JSON data by click `BODY` -> `raw` -> `JSON (application/json)`
3. Click send and see the response text in JSON/XML....

**NOTE:**

1. user refers in the URL your REST Spring controller

```java
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/user")
```

2. register refers in the URL

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", consumes="application/json")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which was solved by importing the `jersey.json` dependency first and then adding this in `web.xml`

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```